# $GLOBALS array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, global

I have the following code

```
function MaximArray($arr)
    {
        $GLOBALS['maxim'] = 0;
        array_walk_recursive($arr,create_function('$item,$key','if($item > $GLOBALS["maxim"]) $GLOBALS["maxim"] = $item;'));
        return $GLOBALS['maxim'];
    }
```

Why does this function work with $GLOBALS['maxim'] but if I declare a variable as global inside function and use it, doesn't work? I learned that $GLOBALS['a'] and global $a are equal.

Example with global variable $maxim:

```
$maxim=0;
    function MaximArray($arr)
    {
        global $maxim;
        array_walk_recursive($arr,create_function('$item,$key','if($item > $maxim) $maxim = $item;'));
        return $maxim;
    }
```

Comment: You should be asking yourself if you really should be using globals at all?

Comment: Why would one enable such a forbidden feature?

Comment: But without global variable how can i memorize the highest value of an multidimensional array?

Comment: @aliz_andrei - a `static` variable might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Spudley it doesn't work either with static variable. It works only with $GLOBALS.

Comment: Ah, by the way, what PHP version are you using? if you're on PHP 5.3 or higher, you should use an inline function rather than the clunky old `create_function()` syntax. That will allow you to use `use $maxim`, as a way to get a variable into the inline function. (if you're using PHP 5.2 or earlier, you can't do that, but you urgently need to upgrade!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on PHP 5.3, you can use a proper inline function rather than the clunky old `create_function()` syntax.

```
array_walk_recursive($arr,function($item,$key) use $maxim {if($item > $maxim) $maxim = $item;}));
```

Note the `use $maxim` bit -- this syntax allows you to pass a local variable into an inline function. This is not possible using `create_function()`.

As I said, this is for PHP 5.3 and later. If you're on PHP 5.2 or earlier then the above syntax won't be available to you. However since PHP 5.2 was declared end-of-life over three years ago, if that's the case then you should be urgently considering an upgrade.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5.3 and the syntax seems to have changed. It would now be: `array_walk_recursive($arr,function($item,$key) use (&$maxim) {if($item > $maxim) $maxim = $item;}));`